# Finding last index of a pattern using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pattern-matching

I want to get the last index of the occurrence of `/<something>[@id` in a string, using purely JavaScript.

Example: `/div[@id` or `/span[@id`  or `/input[@id`

I can get the last index of `[@id` using

```
   var n = xpath.lastIndexOf("[@id");
   var res = xpath.substring(n);
```

But what I need is the index of `/div[@id` starting with `/`

Here is a example of strings I will be playing with,

Example string:

> "/html/body/div[@id='page-
> wrap']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='centercol']/div[@id='ns_1FAHQHPMXDQ2W2ER2822_4131_Widget']/div[@id='ns_1FAHQHPMXDQ2W2ER2822_4131_ItemRow']/div[@class='s9OtherItems']/div[@class='fluid
> asin s9a0']/div[@class='inner']/div[@class='s9hl']/a[@class='title
> ntTitle
> noLinkDecoration']/div[@class='s9ImageWrapper']/div[@class='imageContainer']"

Comment: What's with the `+*+` there? That's certainly syntax error.

Comment: sorry I was just trying that , I edited it

Comment: what result are you expecting from `/div[@id]` string?

Comment: @RahilWazir  I want the index of it , and in the place of div it can even be span,image,input etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be easier without a regular expression:

```
var str = "/div[@id, /span[@id";
var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf("[@id");
if (lastIndex !== -1) {
    --lastIndex;
    while (lastIndex >= 0) {
        if (str.charAt(lastIndex) === "/") {
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (lastIndex !== -1) {
    console.log("Found at " + lastIndex);
}
else {
    console.log("Not found");
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/aneBIPEL/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/aneBIPEL/1/edit)

Comment: nope this gives me ,  when I try to get the substring starting from that index,                                              ='page-wrap']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='centercol']/div[@id='ns_1FAHQHPMXDQ2W2ER2822_4131_Widget']/div[@id='ns_1FAHQHPMXDQ2W2ER2822_4131_ItemRow']/div[@class='s9OtherItems']/div[@class='fluid asin s9a0']/div[@class='inner']/div[@class='s9hl']/a[@class='title ntTitle noLinkDecoration']/div[@class='s9ImageWrapper']/div[@class='imageContainer']

Comment: @CleanX: "nope this gives me _______, when..." ??

Comment: @CleanX: The non-regex solution was easier, and the regex solution I came up with was giving the first index *after* the second-to-last match, not exactly what we wanted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
String.prototype.reverse = function () {
    return this.split("").reverse().join("");
}

String.prototype.lastIndexOf = function(s) {
    var index = this.reverse().indexOf(s.reverse());
    return index >= 0 ? this.length - index - s.length : index;
}
```